# How to display single arbitrary facebook post with a shortcode?

Tags: plugins, posts, shortcode, facebook

Does anyone know of a plugin that can show a single recent Facebook post with a shortcode that works something like this:

```
[fb-recent post="0"]
[fb-recent post="1"]
```

where `post="0"` refers to the most recent post, and `post="1"` refers to the one before that?

Comment: It would help if you could share your code and what you've tried.

Comment: Actually I'm asking if anyone knows of a plugin that can do this. I don't know anything about creating shortcodes.

Comment: Plugin recommends are [off-topic](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) here.  If you give it a shot with code and get stuck, I'm sure people here will be happy to help.